# How to find minimum value from vector?

Tags: c++

How can I find the minimum value from a vector?

```
int main()
{
    int v[100] = { 5, 14, 2, 4, 6 };
    int n = 5;
    int mic = v[0];
enter code here
    for (int i=0; i < v[n]; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] < mic)
            mic = v[i];
    }
    cout< < mic;
}
```

But is not working, what can I do?

Comment: What's the logic behind `i<v[n]`? :)

Comment: Let me guess, another homework? First of all, `v` is not a vector (the question is marked as C++), it is a C-style array. What does "it is not working" mean? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: well , it was loop only through v[n] elements but I've tried to test the array adding same value

Comment: Is not showing the minimum value which is 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an error in your code. This line:

```
for (int i = 0;i < v[n]; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
```

because you want to search `n` places in your vector, not `v[n]` places (which wouldn't mean anything)

Comment: Loop should start from 1 also. No point checking the first value twice.

Answer (score 121):

See [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element).

Examples:

```
std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // STL containers.
std::min_element(v, v + n); // C style arrays where n is the number of elements.
std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v)); // STL containers and C style arrays.
```

Note that for the last option, it is better to apply the 'std 2-step' pattern so it works for user-defined types as well as standard library types:

```
using std::begin, std::end; // Enables argument-dependent lookup: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl
std::min_element(begin(v), end(v));
```

Since C++20, we can also use ranges to avoid having to call begin/end manually:

```
std::ranges::min_element(v);
```

Comment: `std::min_element( std::begin(v), std::end(v) )` for an array in C++11.  Pre-C++11, whatever you named the corresponding functions in your toolbox.

Comment: Not like that , I want "oldschool"

Comment: Also use `std::array<T, N>` instead of `T[N]`.

Comment: @Cristi For the record, `min_element` is from the last millenium. Is that old school enough? ;)

Comment: @JamesKanze - Note that his array has dimension `100`, but only the first `n` elements are to be considered.

Comment: Ah yes.  In that case... But why does the array have `100` elements if only the first `n` are to be considered.  (Probably a side effect of using an array when `std::vector` is indicated.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, ah my sorries, forget about this new stuff :)

Answer (score 62):

You can always use the stl:

```
auto min_value = *std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Comment: I appreciate your showing how to get the minimum value from min_element. It's a self-contained answer!

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::min_element
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {5,14,2,4,6};
    auto result = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    if (std::end(v)!=result)
        std::cout << *result << '\n';
}
```

---

The program you show has a few problems, the primary culprit being the `for` condition: `i<v[n]`. You initialize the array, setting the first 5 elements to various values and the rest to zero. `n` is set to the number of elements you explicitly initialized so `v[n]` is the first element that was implicitly initialized to zero. Therefore the loop condition is false the first time around and the loop does not run at all; your code simply prints out the first element.

Some minor issues:

- avoid raw arrays; they behave strangely and inconsistently (e.g., implicit conversion to pointer to the array's first element, can't be assigned, can't be passed to/returned from functions by value)
- avoid magic numbers. `int v[100]` is an invitation to a bug if you want your array to get input from somewhere and then try to handle more than 100 elements.
- avoid `using namespace std;` It's not a big deal in implementation files, although IMO it's better to just get used to explicit qualification, but it can cause problems if you blindly use it everywhere because you'll put it in header files and start causing unnecessary name conflicts.

Comment: std::min_element return std::end() only if the array/vector is empty.

Comment: @Miszo97 That's true, so in this toy example where the container being searched is not empty we could avoid checking for `end()`. However it's a toy example to show how to use `min_element`, so I show how to check the result in the general case where the container may be empty.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator min_element ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    ForwardIterator lowest = first;
    if (first == last) 
        return last;

    while (++first != last)
    if (*first < *lowest) 
        lowest = first;
    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: Copied and slightly edited from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Answer (score 1):

Try this with

```
 std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int v[100] = {5,14,2,4,6};
    int n = 5;
    int mic = v[0];
    for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        if(v[i] < mic)
        mic = v[i];
    }
    std:cout << mic << std::endl;;
}
```