# Trouble Finding lowest value in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

help me to find out minimum value from the array in function4. I am getting 0 every time. Sometimes I get the value present at first index of the array as minimum value. Kindly review my code and help me to solve the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
void function1(int a[]) {
 for (count=0;count<100;count++) {
        cin >> a[count];
        if (a[count]==0)
        break; }
} 

int function2 (int a[]) {
int sum=0,avg=0;
 for (int n=0;n<count;n++) {
    sum=sum+a[n]; }
    avg=sum/count;
    return avg;

 }
 //maximum value
 int function3 (int a[]) {
    int max1=a[0];
    for (int count=0;count<100;count++) {
      if (a[count]>max1)
        max1=a[count];  
    } 
      return max1;
    }
    //minimum value
    int function4 (int a[]) {   
    int min1=a[0];
    for (int count=0;count<100;count++) {
        if (a[count]<min1){
        min1=a[count];}
        }
        return min1; 
    }

int main () { 
 int a[100]={0};


function1(a); 
cout <<"Average is : "<<function2(a)<<'\n';
cout <<"Maximum Value is : "<<function3(a) <<'\n';
cout <<"Minimum value is : "<<function4(a) << '\n';
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: i know the error is in function4 (having only 3 lines) but i am new to C++ so i am unable to find out the error.

Comment: so, what part of "use a debugger" is unclear to you?

Comment: yes! actually my compiler is asking me to add g++ support and i don't know what it is. (as i said i am new to C++)

Comment: All your functions assume that you have read 100 values into the array. Have you?

Comment: Simplify your life, use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` will remember the number of elements in the container; arrays don't.

Comment: *"Trouble Finding lowest value in array in C++"* - TL;DR. Use `std::min_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can be confused with this line:

```
int a[100]={0}; // This initlizes the whole array to zero.
int a[100]={SOME_VAL}; // This initlizes the first element to SOME_VAL, and the rest of the array to zero.
```

So, probably the array has a lot of zeros, so you are getting the minimum.

But, you don't need to make this functions yourself, just use `std::min_element`

Example:

```
std::cout << "Minimum value is : " << *std::min_element(a,a+99) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to learn programming itself, and not only C++.
If you were to look how C++ gets the smaller element in a container, I'd advise you to look into STL documentation [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element).
This has been asked here before: [How to find minimum value from vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015932/how-to-find-minimum-value-from-vector)

But surely you still need a few hints before:

1. Name your functions intuitively. `function4` is a terrible name for a function whose meaning is to find the lowest/smallest/minimum value in a container. How about calling it `minimum`?
2. Allways search before posting. StackOverflow is smart enough to search for you while you type.
3. The way you pass your array to your functions is a problem. You have a function that makes assumptions on array size with no guaranties. If you simply change your declaration from `a[100]` to `a[10]` your program will be accessing data outside array bounds.There are many solutions for it. Include an extra parameter telling the array size or use `std::vector`, for example.
   1.Please study how parameters (specially arrays) can be passed in C++. Take a look at [Passing arrays to and from functions safely and securely](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/20881/) to begin.
4. **IMPORTANT:** Your data is being populated by `function1()` through console input. ** **are you sure you are filling in 100 values in your array and none is ZERO?** ** If you have any `0` in your array and no negative inputs, obviously the `minimum` value will be `0`!